# Predicate dependence in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following database :

```
sujet(carl).
sujet(bob).
sujet(alice).
objet(bank1).
objet(bank2).
objet(bank3).
objet(bank4).
data(x).
data(y).
data(w).
data(z).
cR(carl,bank2).
cR(co1,alice).
cR(alice,bank1).
cR(alice,bank3).                  
cR(bob,bank1).
cW(carl,bank4).
cW(bob,bank3).
cW(alice,bank3).
cW(bob,bank1).
cK(bob,x).
cS(bank2,w).
cS(bank4,w).
cK(alice,z).
cK(carl,z).
```

I want to find all the results of `cK` and `cS` using the following rules:

```
 cK(S,X):- cS(O,X),cR(S,O).
 cS(O,X):- cK(S,X),cW(S,O).
```

note that the `cK` and the `cS` facts of the database are only there as an initialization.

As you can see the two predicts ck and cS are dependent one another , which means that the results of the the first rule will be used in the second and vice versa.

How can i modifiy the rules in order to get all the cK and cS results starting from the one that are in the database . the breakpoint may be the  redundancy of results .

thanks.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to make your rule with the same name as the facts. You're at high risk of an infinite recursion.

Comment: thats exactly the problem i have , but it is in the problem statement,   .. is there any solution for that ?

Comment: Yes, use different names for the predicate versus the facts. Instead of `cK(S,X) :- cS(O,X), cR(S,O).` use something other than `cK` here. And you might need to use something other than `cS` here as well if you mean the predicate and not the fact (since you should rename the `cS` predicate to not match the fact). You may need to then have multiple clauses for your rules to distinguish whether you're basing a rule on a fact versus the recursive call to the predicate.

Comment: But in that case i will lose the results from the first unification with the facts of the databse. because in the first execution of the rule `cK(S,X) :- cS(O,X), cR(S,O).`  i need to unify cS with the facts in the database , after that the results that i get here alongside with the cK of the database will be used in the rule `cS(O,X):- cK(S,X),cW(S,O).`. and it goes on like that until it found all the results.

Comment: What is the semantic meaning of the predicate? That could help in deciding how to refactor it. It's unclear to me what the predicate is trying to achieve.

Comment: `cK(S,X) :- cS(O,X), cR(S,O)` refers to  a user S can Know a data X iff there is an object O that can Store X and S can Read O . for `cS(O,X):- cK(S,X),cW(S,O)` it refers to an Object O can Store a data X iff there is a user S that can know X and S can Write on O .  now knowing that we have some cK and cS at the begining (as facts) .. I need to find all the others cK an cS.